# How to apply remesh to a limited part of mesh

Tags: remesh

I'd like to apply remesh to a limited part of mesh to erase a slit caused by merging with two different object.[image]

[image]

How should I do?
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmmqKHEN8ib3hH0AKRr96psu0yZW?e=IhXZhO

Comment: I guess it's still the same problem as your previous question, maybe you should simply use the face and smooth the top in order to have the same effect as the top you're showing right now, merging 2 parts can work if the mesh are closed but it's not the case here, I've tried a remesh operation but with no good success

Answer (score 0):

Select your mesh , enter *edit mode* , select the part you wanna apply the modifier to , hit *P* , Separate : *Selection* , exit edit mode .

Now you have a separate portion of the mesh as an individual object , then apply whatever you want to .

Hope it helps .

Comment: And how is one supposed to merge the separate part with the rest of the existing mesh after remeshing? Instead of the old split that should be removed there will be new slits that need to be merged.

Comment: Joining the two meshes again into one object ?

Comment: But the separate remeshed part then has vertices that do no longer fit the mesh where it was taken from and it's back to start - wanting to remesh the area where the two joined meshes meet.

Comment: yeah i see your point , depending on the result he wanna achieve , if the re-meshed part changes dramatically i think my solution wont work , but if he just wants a retouch or a slight remesh a little bit or sculpting and filling edges might help i guess

Comment: The transition from one object to the other should be merged smoothly. Maybe you could elaborate a bit with screenshots how this is achieved, otherwise this is less of a solution than just food for thought. Because it looks like in the end you would have to stitch the different parts together manually which you can already do without separating it.

Comment: It depends on the result he wanna achieve , the human model is already smooth and if he remesh it whats the point of remeshing only a part of it , he could work on the whole object , my solution works for me in previous cases where i needed to treat parts of an object separately then joinin them again , if he can share the blend file and the result or the operations he wants to do specifically i can give it a try